# gets() is causing compilation failure with ''use of undeclared identifier 'gets'" error

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, gets

I am trying to solve e problem. I am taking characters as input and using `gets()`. But the function is showing the above mentioned error.

I don't know why this function is misbehaving. Please help me to find the fault. I am a beginner.

As mentioned the error message is:

```
Use of undeclared identifier 'gets'
```

My C++ code:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char line[1000];
    bool open = true;
    while (gets(line))  //***in this line gets() is showing error***
    {
        int len = strlen(line);
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        {
            if (line[i] == '"')
            {
                if (open)
                {
                    printf("``");
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("''");
                }
                open = !open;
            }
            else
            {
                printf("%c", line[i]);
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

[image]

Comment: There are so many problems in the code you show. Lets begin with `<bits/stdc++.h>`. [*don't* include that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h). Then `gets`, that's [a dangerous function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used) that should never be used. Then there's the problem of only two lines in your code being specific to C++, the rest could be plain C. Who, where or what have taught you "C++"?

Comment: Besides that, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please [don't post images of code](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode). If you have build errors, then copy-paste the full and complete build output (as text!) into the question instead.

Comment: I usually don't use ```bits/stdc++.h>``` but I use the header file in this file because of ```gets()``` was showing error and I tried so many header file but doesn't work. That's why I used ```<bits/stdc++.h>```  in this code.

Answer (score 2):

`std::gets` was deprecated in C++11 and removed from C++14, [this a dangerous function and it should never be used](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4309845/6865932), though some compilers still provide it, it looks like it's not your case, which is a good thing.

You should use something like [`std::getline`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/), note that for this you'll need the `line` argument to be `std::string`.

```
string line;

//...

while (getline(cin, line)){
    //...
}
```

Alternatively, if you really need a `char` array, you can use [`fgets`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/) instead:

```
char line[1000];
//...
while(fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin)){
   //remove newline character using strcspn
   line[strcspn(line, "\n")] = '\0';
   //or with C++ std::replace
   replace(&line[0], &line[1000], '\n', '\0'); //&line[1000] one past the array end
   //...
}
```

Side note:

Consider [not using `using namespace std;`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/6865932) and  [`#include <bits/stdc++.h>`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095/6865932), follow the links for details.

Comment: Oh... I am using C++14. That's why it is showing error.

Comment: @SatyajitRoy This doesn't mean you should go back to C++11. This means you should stop using `gets`, and perhaps start really learning C++.

Answer (score 0):

gets() is deprecated as already mentioned. Read about it [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/gets)

But let's get to the root cause of why you got the error in the first place.
An

> undeclared identifier 'gets'

error is because the compiler can't find the declaration of the function you are using. In your case gets() is defined in stdio.h

I also see that you're using [std::getline()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) as recommended and for that you need to include the `string` header.

Take a look at the 2 links I've mentioned to understand proper usage.